# Does MiniSAT need exponential time?

Tags: satisfiability, sat-solvers

I'm asking for a sequence of instances for SAT, one instance for each length, such that the sequence takes exponential time with MiniSAT.

Comment: What research have you done? Have you tried standard instances which take exponential time on any DPLL-based SAT solver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When pure CDCL solvers (such as MiniSAT, I believe) are run on unsatisfiable instances, their transcript can be converted to a Resolution refutation of the instance. In particular, the running time of the solver is lower bounded by the length of the smallest Resolution refutation of the instance. There are instances which are known to take exponential length to refute in Resolution, for example the Pigeonhole Principle on $n+1$ pigeons and $n$ holes. Such instances will take exponential time to refute on any pure CDCL solver.

Comment: You are right! I tried 10 pigeons and 9 holes and got a running time of 2 seconds. But when I tried 11 pigeons and 10 holes, MiniSAT ran for 100 seconds before running into a bug. I can conclude this sequence of instances is exponentially timed. Time for a better solver.

Comment: Some more data: 6 pigeons, 0 second; 7 pigeons, 0.016 second; 8, 0.068; 9, 0.268; 10, 2.396; 11, 173.384; 12, 1667.47; 13, 124068. I mentioned a "bug," i.e., the number of original variables and clauses drop as the solver progresses. But it is a commonplace phenomenon, and it's perhaps not a bug. Anyway, the runtime is really exponential.

Comment: @ZiruiWang Minisat performs some SAT instance simplification on-the-fly, which can lead to a decreasing number of variables over time. Pidgeonhole principle problems are difficult for *every* SAT solver that is based on search. Non-search based ones do not run well on most practical SAT instances, however. You could use constraint propagation solvers, though, which often have special support for bijective mapping problems.

Comment: @DCTLib What are "constraint propagation SAT solvers"?

Comment: @ZiruiWang Sorry, I mean "constraint programming" and not "constraint propagation". See Wikipedia for a list of tools: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction#Constraint_satisfaction_toolkits

Comment: Can we make the stronger claim that a polynomial-time SAT solver cannot verify its correctness on unsatisfiable instances?

Comment: @ZiruiWang This is equivalent to P≠NP.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I thought the answer is yes, because a correct solver's execution itself is a proof that the instance is unsatisfiable, no?

Comment: @ZiruiWang That's why it's equivalent to P≠NP.